# Finding closest value in Python with CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am a novice programmer. I am trying to analyze some a simple CSV file called test_score using Python (I have a significantly larger file I'm analyzing, but I condensed it down to test my code).

The CSV file looks like:

```
First Name,Last Name,Gender,Score
John,Smith,Male,100
Jane,Doe,Female,97
Henry,Vo,Male,75
Jennifer,Bradley,Female,80
```

The goal is to find the closest score based on the user input. The user chooses whether it's a male or female. The user also inputs a score.

My code looks like this:

```
import csv
user_gender = input("Male or Female\n")
user_score = input("Closest test score\n")

path = r'C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\Exercise\test_score.csv'
with open(path, 'r') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for line in readCSV:
    first_name = line['First Name']
    last_name = line['Last Name']
    gender = line['Gender']
    score = int(line['Score'])

    if user_gender.lower() == gender.lower():
        print (score)
```

So far, the code works for finding all the scores based on gender. What code do I need to add to specifically find the score closest to the user input score?

Thank you

Comment: Just look for the `min()` of `abs(score-user_score)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min`:

```
import csv
def closest_score(val, gender = 'check_all'):
  data = list(csv.reader(open('filename.csv')))[1:]
  if gender == 'check_all':
    return min(data, key=lambda x:abs(val-int(x[-1])))
  return min([i for i in data if i[-2].lower() == gender.lower()], key=lambda x:abs(val-int(x[-1])))

print(closest_score(70))
```

Output:

```
['Henry', 'Vo', 'Male', '75']
```

Edit: if you wish to utilize `DictReader`, then the function becomes:

```
def closest_score(val, gender = 'check_all'):
  data = csv.DictReader(open('filename.csv'), delimiter=',')
  if gender == 'check_all':
    return min(data, key=lambda x:abs(val-int(x['Score'])))
  return min((i for i in data if i['Gender'].lower() == gender.lower()), key=lambda x:abs(val-int(x['Score'])))
```

Comment: Any reason to move away from the `DictReader()` and instead of `i[-2]` use `i['Gender']`?

Comment: @AChampion `i[-2]` is shorter (and perhaps cleaner), but `list(csv.reader(open('filename.csv')))[1:]` can easily be replaced with `csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')` if the OP so chooses.

Comment: I would perhaps disagree with 'cleaner' - `-2` is magic `'Gender'` is very obvious for anyone reading the code - but this maybe a matter of  personal style. Note: you are creating multiple `list`s unnecessary, `data = csv.reader(...)` is sufficient as is a generator expression in the `min()` call.